# When would a blocking call to flock fail?

Tags: linux, perl, file, locking, flock

I was reading about [flock](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html). The example has this line:
`flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die "Cannot lock mailbox - $!\n";`
This call is a blocking call right? So if the lock is already taken the call blocks.
I assume that if the call returns the lock is granted. So when would the `die` would occur?

Answer (score 9):

`flock` is a wrapper for the system call of the same name. `$!` is set by the system. So consult the system's documentation for your answer.

On my system, as per `man 2 flock`,

- `EBADF`: `fd` is not an open file descriptor.
- `EINTR`: While waiting to acquire a lock, the call was interrupted by delivery of a signal caught by a  handler;  see  signal(7).
- `EINVAL`: `operation` is invalid.
- `ENOLCK`: The kernel ran out of memory for allocating lock records.
- `EWOULDBLOCK`: The file is locked and the `LOCK_NB` flag was selected.